# Refresh Page with URL Hash after Submitting Form with jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, hash

I'm a long time self taught user, just never had an issue that wasn't already answered in some form or another.  Awesome community thank you all!

So I am dumbfounded as to why `javascript` will not properly refresh my page.

I have a very large page that I use with `jquery` and vertical tabs tagged with url hashes.  This is a new function I recently added after updating to the newest version.

Upon clicking submit the form refreshes and if $_POST[update] is set it will run a set of queries.  Then I have a `javascript` timeout that refreshes the page (ideally to the correct tab ex: home/database.php?file=101#tab3)

an excerpt of my messy code:

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
    { do a bunch of sql stuff
    ....
    <pre>
    <?PHP
        //unset update variable
        $_POST = array();

        //print_r(get_defined_vars());

    ?>
    </pre>
    </br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Redirect() {
            $('#redirect').trigger('click');
        }
        var currenturl = window.location.href;

        document.write("<form action=" + currenturl +"><input type=submit name=redirect value=Redirect></form>");

        document.write("</br>You will be redirected back to the file in 2 seconds.");


        setTimeout('Redirect()', 2000);
        </script>
    <?php
    mysql_close($conn);
}
else
    { display usual data....check boxes etc
```

Now I've tried refreshing in every conceivable way.  I clear out the $_POST array so the page should reload displaying information, but it doesn't.  However my confirmation of queries being ran show that 0 rows updated, so its not triggering the sql but also isn't properly refreshing still.

I found a function that stored the last clicked tab in the browsers session, however when you switch files, it would skip to that tab. Instead I would want to show the default tab.

I even tried made a button that on click it goes to the proper url which is shown above.  It works when I click it manually but does not work when I trigger it via `javascript`. Even goes to the appropriate tab.

I am updating the url in the address bar using the below function.  Also using the latest version of chrome.

```
    <script>
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {                   
            window.location.replace('#' + $(ui.newPanel).attr('id'));
            var curTab = $(ui.newPanel).attr('id');
            console.log(curTab);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you instead of sending that number after `<form_url>?<params>#3` send that number as a `request param in the url`, for example like this `<form_url>?tab=3`?

Comment: Ive tried doing something like that however, the fact that the page isnt properly refreshing would be an easier fix.

Comment: You are wrong, changing the way you send `tab` attribute to as I pointed out is easier and will work in all cases.